# where can i get the sandbox tag library jar file

Tags: jsf, jar, sandbox

I am trying to use sanbox in my jsf application. So i need tag library for sandbox or jar file
can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309016/where-can-i-download-tomahawk-and-sandbox-tag-libraries-or-jar-files

Comment: Wappow..dupe by the same user

Comment: @Radhika check your original question for answers, don't reask the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify which Sandbox Jar you need to use from [here](http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=sandbox+limit%3Anone)